# Layered mvc, what is the responisiblty of controller

Tags: java, oop, playframework, architecture

In my current project we use mvc layers 
- we have ajax js app as view, controllers, models, service layer as bl, orm as dal.

My question is what exactly are the controllers responsible to, for example my js app has a view that shows all the names of the items I own,
Should the controller call the service layer, retreive all the items, map them to their name and send to the view or - should the controller return all the items to the view and the view would take only the name?

In conclusion, what kind of logic should a controller of ajax app have? Should the js app proccess the data or the controller ? Or even the service layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified the role of the controller as sitting between the view and the model. 
This question is subjective, with the answer depending on opinion. As a rule, the less the view has to do the better.